# Delete rows from cassandra table using pyspark or cql query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a table with lots of columns, for ex. *test_event* and also I have another table *test* in the same keyspace that contains id's of rows I have to delete from *test_event*.

I tried deleteFromCassandra, but it doesn't works because spark cannot see SparkContext. 
I found some solutions used DELETE FROM, but it was written in scala.

After about hundred attempts I finally get confused and asked for your help. Can somebody do it with me step by step?

Comment: Can you show the code - `deleteFromCassandra` just works, maybe you're missing some imports

Comment: @AlexOtt test.deleteFromCassandra(keyspace, test_event)

Comment: You need to specify keyColumns parameter

Comment: Show the structure of table with IDs, and primary key of main table

Comment: I missed yesterday that it was for pyspark - see the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

def main_function():

  sql = SQLContext(sc)
  tests = sql.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
               load(keyspace="your keyspace", table="test").where(...)
  for test in tests:
    delete_sql = "delete from test_event where id = " + test.select('id')
    sql.execute(delete_sql)
```

Be aware of deleting one row at a time is not a best practice on spark but the above code is just an example to help you figure out your implementation.

Comment: 'TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable'. Should I rewrite it as UDF?

Comment: I made function that take an argument "id" and now I can't understand how to apply it. I mean iterate through test table with ids.

Comment: Check the names of your data frame, column 'id' might not exist. if you want to remove id by id then yes you will need to iterate just keep in mind that it is not a good practice for spark, it is recommended you filter and then remove everything that matches. For Cassandra you could remove by partition key for example.

Answer (score 1):

Spark Cassandra Connector (SCC) itself provides only Dataframe API for Python.  But there is a [pyspark-cassandra package](https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra#pyspark_cassandracassandrardd) that provides RDD API on top of the SCC, so deletion could be performed as following.

Start pyspark shell with (I've tried with Spark 2.4.3):

```
bin/pyspark --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=IPs\
    --packages anguenot:pyspark-cassandra:2.4.0
```

and inside read data from one table, and do delete.  You need to have source data to have the columns corresponding to the primary key. It could be full primary key, partial primary key, or only partition key - depending on it, Cassandra will use corresponding tombstone type (row/range/partition tombstone).

In my example, table has primary key consisting of one column - that's why I specified only one element in the array:

```py
rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "m1")
rdd.deleteFromCassandra("test","m1", keyColumns = ["id"])
```